# Напишите функцию sum, которая работает так: sum(a)(b) = a+b

Tags: javascript

```js
function sum(a){
  return function(b){
    return a + b
  }
}
console.log(sum(2)(3))
```

1. Функции работают в 2 фазы
2. Первая фаза инициализация
3. Создается внутреннее лексическое окружение (объект)
4. Вторая фаза присваивание
5. Внутреннее лексическое окружение присваивает аргументы, переменные, функции
6. Запускаем функцию sum()
7. Где происходит пункт 2,3,4,5
8. Аргументам сразу присваивается значение на фазе 2
9. Функции типа Function Declaration сразу создаются работающими
10. У Function Declaration если в теле функции указана переменная (аргумент) у которой присваивание значения происходит на внешней функции (аргумент сразу получает присваивание при запуске функции) или в объекте Window - это происходит на фазе первой инициализация
11. Происходит следующее запускаем функцию sum()

```js
// Создается лексическое окружение функции

{
 a: 2,
 анонимная функция: function(b){
 // Создается лексическое окружение функции
   {
      b: 3
   };
   return 2 + 3
 }
};
```

12. Происходит возвращение функции
13. Правильно ?

Comment: @Grundy Здравствуйте а чего сразу по вашей ссылке меня отправили ? надо было на международную олимпиаду по математике отправить я на нем  тоже ничего не понимаю

Comment: Если бы на олимпиаде по математике были такие задачи можно было бы и туда отправить.